# Callback function in a child passed from a parent is undefined during pre-rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When running `npm run build`, I get the following error:

> Error: You provided an `onClose` prop to the `Dialog`, but the value is not a function. Received: undefined

This is because during pre-rendering/build, there is no dependency between the parent and child (maybe due to my implementation?), so the callback function is undefined by the time. How can I tell the compiler this dependency? Or get rid of this error?

```
//Parent
const Parent = () => {
  const [isOpen, SetIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <input
      onClick = setIsOpen(true)
    >Click <input />
    {isOpen && <Child callback={() => setOpen(false}}
  )
}

//Child
const Child = ({callback}) => {
  <Modal
    onClose={callback}
  >
  ...
   <Modal />
}

//Modal
const Modal ({onClose, ...}) => {
  return (
    <Transition.Root>
      <Dialog
        onClose={onClose}
        ...
        >
        ...
        <Dialog />
     <Transition.Root />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the component file is under project directory where Next.js does not allow us to export components from there, so it was not a code issue.